# Indexing Text on Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9.4-beta

A project I've been working for a few weeks stopped working for no reason because Xcode got stucked on "Indexing text". I can't Build the project anymore. If I try to build, Xcode freezes and I have to force quit. This happens every time I'm using Xcode!

I tried deleting Xcode, downloading it again and cleaning all derived data but those didn't help.

I'm using Xcode 9.4.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: clear derivedData and completely close xCode and reOpen it, wait for the completion if indexing.

Comment: Xcode 9.4 is latest and still it in beta version. its not stable version. my suggestion is use to stable xcode version.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in Xcode 11.3, on Catalina, in 2023, where this is the highest release of Xcode that Catalina supports. I would HOPE that this version was "stable".

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Xcode (10.2.1) just got stuck on "Indexing Text". I tried what the internet suggested. Unfortunately, it didn't help. What gave it away was that it was happening on all my projects and not just one. So I restarted my computer and it worked just fine. Not sure what was the issue though.

**Just in case:**

- Clean & close project.
- Clear DerivedData.
- Rebuild project.

**What worked for me:**

- Restart computer.

Comment: Same with Xcode11.2: restart fixed the endless indexing problem

Comment: Same with Xcode 11.3.1 on MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)  running macOS 10.15.3

Comment: Same here with Xcode 12.4, a restart of the mac mini fixed the indexing issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Just 'Restart the computer' solved my endless indexing.